# JavaFX error-dialog doesn't show up in runnable jar file because of changed graphic

Tags: java, javafx, jar, imageview, alert

I made a JavaFX error-dialog and changed default image.

This seemed fine in the first place, but when I exported the project as a runnable *.jar, this dialog simply didn't show up anymore.

I figured, when I leave the image out everything works fine but this is not a solution for me.

**Code**

```
public static void alert() throws IOException {
    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
    alert.setTitle("FATAL ERROR");
    alert.setHeaderText("/*Error message*/");

    ImageView alertImage = new ImageView(new Image(new FileInputStream(new File("*/Image-path*/"))));   
    alert.setGraphic(alertImage);

    alert.setContentText("/*query*/");

    //Button funktions
    Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();

    if (result.isPresent() && (result.get() == ButtonType.OK)) {
        /*unimportant code*/
    }

    if (result.isPresent() && (result.get() == ButtonType.CANCEL)) {
        /*unimportant code*/
    }

}
```

Comment: is `*/Image-path*/` a real path in your code of some form of redaction?

Comment: no, the real path is "src/Images/image.png"

Comment: it is unlikely that your jar contains a folder called `src`. Use a zip-tool to inspect the contents.

Comment: the `src` folder actually isn't part of the jar-file, but it contains the Images-folder so I changed the path to `"Images/image.png"`. but this also didn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your image as follows:

```
ImageView alertImage = new ImageView(getClass().getResource("/Images/image.png").toExternalForm());
```

It uses the [`ImageView(String url)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html#ImageView-java.lang.String-) constructor which will load the `Image` for you. As the `Images` folder is inside the `jar` the `getResource` will return a 'special' URL to that file. You can't reference it *as* a file, as the JAR is the single file that contains the image, there is no separate file of the image.

Comment: Thanks so much, this worked for me. but I couldn't use `getClass()` since my method is `static` so I used my `GUIclass.class` instead of `getClass()` which worked fine.